# Page closes itself when pressing play button on android when using Youtube iFrame api

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

The initial page loads, and when pressing the youtube play button, the attached image shows up and then the page crashes. After that I am taken back to the previous page.

[image: Image before page crash]

The issue is not consistent and I am not getting log for the issue.

Can anybody please help...

This is the log that I get 


07-27 19:47:39.181    3007-3050/com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel W/Adreno-GSL﹕ : ioctl fd 35 code 0x400c0907 (IOCTL_KGSL_DEVICE_WAITTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument

07-27 19:47:39.181    3007-3050/com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel W/Adreno-EGL﹕ : EGL_BAD_PARAMETER

07-27 19:47:39.181    3007-3050/com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_fence_egl.cc(63)] Failed to wait for EGLSync. error:EGL_BAD_PARAMETER

07-27 19:47:39.181    3007-3050/com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:gl_fence_egl.cc(65)] Check failed: g_ignore_egl_sync_failures.

07-27 19:47:39.381     882-1585/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{32180b4c u0 com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel/com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel.DetailsActivity}

07-27 19:47:39.385      882-895/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{31ed81af u0 com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel/com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel.PlayActivity}

07-27 19:47:39.591     882-1556/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel (pid 3007) has died

07-27 19:47:39.596     882-1556/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{2097b98d u0 com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel/.PlayActivity t3287}: app died, no saved state

07-27 19:47:39.622      882-918/? V/WindowManager﹕ Based on layer: Adding window Window{1bbfeaf0 u0 Starting com.app.tastetycoons.recipereel} at 11 of 17

I use a webview for initiating this player. Code as follows

 In onCreate--

```
wvVideo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvVideo); 

wvVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
wvVideo.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); 

wvVideo.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND); 
wvVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 

WebSettings webSettings = wvVideo.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
wvVideo.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Comment: can you share some code around the issue!!

Comment: Is this a webview or youtube player ?

Comment: @sunilsunny it is a webview

Comment: Two questions: 
What is the device and the Android OS you are testing with?
I am not able to see the URL of the YouTube video to be displayed in the as webView using iframe api. Please paste that too. 
One suggestion is to try turning "off" the hardware accelerator. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: @AniV The device is Moto X, 5.1 lollypop. The url is http://tastetycoons.com/youtubesanif.html?videoid=M3n8zh2OewA. One thing I want to ask is, in a lot of stack post people suggest that I have to be turning acceleration 'on' to deal with problems like these. why is it that you suggest the opposite?!?

Comment: HardwareAccelerated="true" is a GPU intensive operation. Even though it enriches the quality of the media there might be performance degradation because of extra consumption of the CPU cycles for rendering of the video. It varies at OEM level, so nice to check by turning hardwareacceleration off.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,I am guessing you are running this on a Samsung device.I too have this issue and fixed this by this single line on shouldOverrideUrlLoading .No need of setting chromeclient else where.Also try enabling android:hardwareAccelerated="true" on manifest.

```
   @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        wvVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```

Comment: This is helping to an extent I guess.. The frequency of the crash has come down.. Thank bro.. :)

Comment: Only crashes came down .Not fixed the problem ?